# How to assign rdsadmin role to postgres user in postgres rds instance?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

As per the AWS documentation for postgres rds , by default postgres or admin user  doesn't have superuser privileges. How to assign rdsadmin for the postgres user. Can someone help me with this?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html

I get below error when performing superuser tasks with postgres user

```
ERROR: must be superuser to alter superusers
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/661661/why-cant-i-create-a-superuser-in-aws-postgresql-instance

Comment: Check the link below, also you might want to post what the permissions on your postgres user looks like(do a `\du`)? For any other user they need to be a part of the rds_super role to perform `su` activities in PG.
Link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.Roles.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.Roles.rds_superuser